# Script to edit a text file on a Linux Redhat Server

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

The task I am trying to achieve is to write a script which accesses a Red Hat Server, navigates to a certain directory, and adds things to a text file. How would I go about this task? what scripting language do I use? etc.

I don't have any experience in scripting languages, I'm only really an expert in Java applications and occasional C#.

Hope somebody can help. This would be extremely useful to me.

Comment: I'd say it does not matter which language you use, there are plenty readily available under linux. The first question is how to connect and communicate, so what protocol you want to use. So what access do you have to that server?

Comment: You may put most of your file handling logic to a shell script in your redhat server. Then call it using `ssh` from client machine. Ensure key exchange set up so that ssh will not prompt for password.

Comment: Greyson had the kind of thing i'm after. So for example a file with a list of usernames, lets say accessfile.txt sits inside opt/storage/accessfolder. I want to ultimately make a GUI in C# or java to run this bat file and add a person I give it to the text file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to append a line, you can use SSH (for the connection) and just concatenate to the end of the file like so:

```
echo "New line to text file" | ssh myserver.com 'cat >> /var/myfile.txt'
```

If you're trying to change the contents, then you'll need to download the file before running it through a utility such as `sed` or `awk` and then uploading it back to the server. `scp` can be used to securely download and upload the file, but describing `sed` or `awk` here is beyond the scope of a brief answer.